# How to write a music bot with Discord,py rewrite without downloading the song

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to write a discord bot that plays music but everything I have seen uses FFmpeg to download the music. I was trying to just play the URL. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can see some examples below:

[Using FFMPEG](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py)

[Using Lavalink](https://github.com/PythonistaGuild/Wavelink#getting-started)

**Lavalink** is more preferred